# Training dataset for sentiment analysis of restaurant reviews

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, training-data

I am trying to analyze the customer reviews for restaurants and was wondering if there was any particular dataset available for this domain?

If not, what would be the best training dataset for this category?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [SemEval-2015 ABSA Restaurant Reviews - Train Data](http://metashare.ilsp.gr:8080/repository/browse/semeval-2015-absa-restaurant-reviews-train-data/b2ac9c0c198511e4a109842b2b6a04d751e6725f2ab847df88b19ea22cb5cc4a/). This dataset is distributed for Aspect Based Sentiment Analysis (ABSA).